# Adding a file to Android internal storage at design time

Tags: android, storage

I've been messing around with Android, after having read Android Application Development for Dummies, and nothing else (just to illustrate how little I know) I'm trying to create my first useful, but very simple app.
The app should do the following:

1. prompt me for a password
2. read a string (persisted somewhere in the memory)
3. use my password as a key to decrypt the string
4. parse the string as xml and display the data to me

other than being a coding exercise, this would serve me as a sneaky way of storing sensitive data that's too copious to remember.
I don't want the app to handle input of this data, I want it to come pre-filled with it. (never mind reusability right now) I don't want to hardcode the string in the code though. 
I've decided to store the string in a file in the app's internal storage (if this is a bad idea, feel free to suggest something else). I've found plenty of examples on how to work with these files. But they all deal with creating the file at runtime. What I'd like to do is create the file as part of my Eclipse project, and then have it available to the app at runtime.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Use SharedPreference for keeping password like String in Android app.

Comment: The string I want to store is not a mere password. It's a bit more data (about 3 or 4KB), represented as XML. I use the word "string" to describe it, because I intend to smush it into a single encrypted string. I don't want it editable as a SharedPreference, and I want to avoid having to input it in the app itself. I'm not sure SharedPreference would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1):

> What I'd like to do is create the file as part of my Eclipse project,
>   and then have it available to the app at runtime. Is it possible to do
>   this?

Yes it's possible, you can create your file in the `assets` or `res/raw` directory, then fill its content when the app is running.

However, I'm not sure if this is the best place if you have sensitive information to store in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try that. Don't worry, the data will only be stored in encrypted form. I know it's not the best practice, but as I said, this is just beginner's experimental app. A dirty quick-fix, if you will.